# doBye method of sip servlet not calling while doing the junit testing through SIPDriver

Tags: java, servlets, sip-servlet, mobicents-sip-servlets

I have written one sipservlet. while doing the testing through SIPdriver, i am seeing doInvite,doResponce method is calling but doBye method is not calling. Please help. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: There is no way to help with so little info, please post your questions to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobicents-public with code sample and logs files of such a test call.

Answer (score 0):

Subsequent SIP requests (like the BYE) typically go direct from peer-to-peer (without going through the proxy). To cause your application to receive the BYE and indeed all other subsequent requests, do one of the following:

1. On receipt of the INVITE, proxy the request having set record route to true on the proxy (request.getProxy().setRecordRoute(true);) first.
2. Implement your application behaviour as a back-to-back user agent (b2bua). This is a much more complex application model to implement, but does also yield much more control over the SIP sessions.

Hope this helps!